# pandas dataframe groupby index and convert row values into columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

While I think I could do this naively and poorly, I'm interested to learn a more elegant and efficient approach.

Given the following dataframe:

```py
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({'flavor':['goober','tronic','goober','tronic'], 'points':[42,55,31,101]}, index=['foo','foo','bar','bar'])

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
     flavor  points
foo  goober      42
foo  tronic      55
bar  goober      31
bar  tronic     101
```

I would like to groupby the index, and convert values from `flavor` column into column headers themselves, completely throwing away the `flavor` and `points`.  So the final result would look like:

```py
In [44]: pd.DataFrame({'goober':[42,31], 'tronic':[55,101]}, index=['foo','bar'])
Out[44]: 
     goober  tronic
foo      42      55
bar      31     101
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with convert index to column first and then remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().pivot('index', 'flavor','points').rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)
print (df)
     goober  tronic
bar      31     101
foo      42      55
```

Or use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('flavor', append=True)['points']
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df)
     goober  tronic
bar      31     101
foo      42      55
```

Comment: This is obviously a toy example, at scale, would these differ in performance and/or memory usage?  Appreciate the answer.

Comment: @ghukill - hmmm, generally pivoting are really complicated operation, so not easy says what solution is better. The best test with data.

Comment: Any advice on when `.unstack()` is particularly helpful?  maybe an SO question/answer?  No worries if not, but I'd like to build some intuition around `pivot` and `unstack`, and where they shine.

Comment: @ghukill - Sure, it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael!  All much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print( pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, columns='flavor', values='points') )
```

Prints:

```
flavor  goober  tronic
bar         31     101
foo         42      55
```

---

Note: If you don't need `aggfunc`, use `.pivot()` instead. As @jezrael pointed out in the comments.

Comment: There is aggregation `mean`, OP need it?

Comment: @jezrael You've right, `.pivot` is preferable here.

Comment: ok, rather delete comments here ;) Maybe somebody should be angry ;)